# Rails undefined local variable or method `line_item'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, undefined

Hello I have ran into a bit of trouble when create this conditional for a cart I built in my website to display a total when a part is on sale. In my schema I have parts, line_items which has an id of parts and carts, and carts. Parts have a attribute of discount. If a part has a discount it will display the discount and the new price of the part. My line_items has a method called line_item_discount which will create a new sum of the parts if one part includes a discount. Although it displays the part, the discount, and the new price, the cart total is not updating it.

I created a method called total_price_with_discount here

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_part(part_id)
    current_part = line_items.find_by(part_id: part_id)
    if current_part
      current_part.quantity += 1
    else
      current_part = line_items.build(part_id: part_id)
    end
    current_part
  end

  def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price}
  end

  def total_price_with_discount
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price.line_item_discount}
  end
```

Now where I am getting stuck is inside the _cart partial I tried to create a conditional where if a part has a discount it will use the total_price_with_discount method but if a part does not have a discount it will use the total_price. I have tried quite a few ways to create the conditional but i keep getting messages like this

[image: undefined error]

for some reason carts has no instance of line_items or parts it appears.

Here are my tables for carts, parts, and line_items

```
create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.decimal  "subtotal"
  end

create_table "parts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.text    "description"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.integer "price"
    t.boolean "active"
    t.integer "discount"
    t.string  "image"
    t.integer "quantity"
  end
  create_table "line_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "part_id"
    t.integer  "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
    t.integer  "quantity",   default: 1
  end
```

my parts model

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :line_items

  before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item


  def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
    if line_items.empty?
      return true
    else
      errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
      return false
    end
end


  def subtotal
    parts.collect { |part| part.valid? ? (part.quantity * part.unit_price) : 0}.sum
  end


  def apply_discount
    price - (discount.to_f/100 * price)
  end

end
```

my line_items model

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :part
  belongs_to :cart

  def total_price
    part.price * quantity
  end

  def line_item_discount
    part.price - (part.discount.to_f/100 * part.price) * quantity
  end

end
```

and here is the partial view thats throwing the error

```
<h2>Your Cart</h2> <table>
    <%= render(cart.line_items) %>
<tr class="total_line">
<td colspan="2">Total</td>
<%unless cart.line_items.part.discount?%>
<td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></td>
<%end%>

<%if cart.line_items.part.discount?%>
<td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price_with_discount) %></td>
<%end%>
    </tr>
  </table>

<%= button_to 'Empty cart', cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Thanks for any help and advice with this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the `Cart` model I would add:

```
has_many :parts, through: :line_items
```

Add a scope to the `Part` model:

```
scope :with_discounts, -> { where.not(discount: nil) }
```

Then change the view to:

```
<td class="total_cell">
  <%if cart.parts.with_discount.any?%>
    <%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price_with_discount) %>
  <%else%>
    <%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %>
  <%end%>
</td>
```

**Update: Instead of the above, I believe the code below is more efficient, but I'll present both options and let you pick.**

Below we'll always use `line_item_discount` in the `total_price` method within the `LineItem` model:

```
def total_price
  (part.price * quantity) - line_item_discount
end

def line_item_discount
  return 0 if part.discount.blank?
  (part.discount.to_f/100 * part.price) * quantity
end
```

Then you don't even need the if statement within the view, `total_price` will work either way:

```
<td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></td>
```

You can then remove the `total_price_with_discount` method from the `Cart` model.

We can also tweak the `total_price` method within the `Cart` model:
**(Works with either code choice)**

```
def total_price
  line_items.sum(:total_price)
end
```

Comment: I was using the bottom strategy you provided me with and it seems this code is actually take the actually percentage number as the price instead of the discounted price

Comment: oh wait I'm so sorry I forgot to take the total_price_with_discount out of the model

Comment: You'll also have to alter the calculation within `line_item_discount` (I've modified the code within the answer). It was actually calculating the total price after discount, instead of just the discount itself, just realized.

Answer (score 1):

In your view you're calling `cart.line_items.part` but `line_items` is a collection of multiple `LineItem` objects, `.part` is not a valid method on that collection object.

As you can see in your error, the `part` method is missing for `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`.

You should create a scope on `LineItem` like:

```
scope :with_discounted_part, { joins(:part).where.not(part: { discount: nil }) }
```

And then in your view you can do:

```
<% if cart.line_items.with_discounted_part %>
```